# How can I match SqlDependency with sys.dm_qn_subscriptions

Tags: c#, sql-server

I create a SqlDependency with:

```
SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
```

but I cannot find dependency.id (or any other property) in:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_qn_subscriptions
```

Is there a way to match them up so I can check if dependency I created is still alive.

Comment: Is this the wrong forum for this? It's a c# thing so I think this is the right place

Comment: Your question's fine, just nobody's seen fit to answer yet. Have an upvote.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you! Would prefer an answer...

Comment: I'm sure you would... but I've found `SqlDependency` very fiddly to set up and maintain. Not much better than old-fashioned polling, or triggers that insert messages in a service broker queue, so I'm not really motivated to dig in deep.

Comment: Yes, you have to keep resetting it - but It actually works quite well, but I have need to multiple dependencies now and would like to know which is which

Answer (score 0):

I found an article that might be helpful to you: [Instant Database Changes Using SignalR](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3334/instant-database-changes-using-signalr)

After execute AddSqlDependency method, sqlCommand.ExecuteReader() must be executed in order to make it works.

Hope this is working for you.